# Changing values of an object in a LINQ-statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I want to add some calculated properties to an EntityObject without loosing the possibility of querying it agains the database.

I created a partial class and added the fields I need in the object. Than I wrote a static function "AttachProperties" that should somehow add some calculated values. I cannot do this on clientside, since several other functions attach some filter-conditions to the query.

The functions should look like this:

```
return query.Select(o =>
{
   o.HasCalculatedProperties = true;
   o.Value = 2;

   return o;
});
```

In my case the calculated value depends on several lookups and is not just a simple "2". This sample works with an IEnumerable but, of course, not with an IQueryable

I first created a new class with the EntityObject as property and added the other necessary fields but now I need this extended class to be of the same basetype.

Answer (score 1):

First, in my opinion changing objects in a Select() is a bad idea, because it makes something else happen (state change) than the method name suggests (projection), which is always a recipe for trouble. Linq is rooted in a functional programming (stateless) paradigm, so this kind of usage is just not expected.

But you can extend your class with methods that return a calculation result, like:

```
partial class EntityObject
{
    public int GetValue()
    {
        return this.MappedProp1 * this.MappedProp2;
    }
}
```

It is a bit hard to tell from your question whether this will work for you. If generating a calculated value involves more than a simple calculation from an object's own properties it may be better to leave your entities alone and create a services that return calculation results from an object graph.

Comment: In my scenario the calculated value depends on multie looksup and needs to be called for several objects. So calculating them on the first call will cause many, unncecessary queries. Is it not possible to attach some of the needed properties to an IQueriable?

Comment: That sounds like a [decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) pattern. Ray's solution would get close to this if you would let `OExtended` inherit from `O`.

Comment: Let `OExtended` inherit from `O` works for the attached properties. But as soon as any other Linq-filtercriteriums are added, I get an error `The specified type member '{0}' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` where `type member` is the name of the used property.

For example `context.Os.AttachProperty()` works, `context.Os.AttachProperty().Where(o => o.IsEnabled)` throws the exception.

Comment: I don't get it. OExtended should not be part of your entity model, just inherited from an entity. Something like `.Where(o => o.IsEnabled)`, where `IsEnabled` is not a mapped member, is only possible if you convert to IEnumerable first, i.e. fetch data into memory and continue with linq to objects.

Comment: But Linq to Enity is able to handle primitive classes - I do NOT need to use linq to objects. If `OExtedned` does not inherit from `O`, but implement a property of type `O` I can stay in my IQueryable-context.

And in my case `IsEnabled` is a mapped member. So I do not get the exception. Maybe he looses his mappinginformation because of the inheritance?

Comment: I think you should show more code, especially the places where exceptions occur. We're getting our wires crossed, I' afraid.

Comment: I'm calling `objets.AttachProperty().Where(o => o.IsEnabled)` where `AttachProperty` returns `objects.Select(o => new ExtendedO() { Value = 2});` and `o.IsEnabled` is a mapped property from the database.

That's all - and an exception `The specified type member 'IsEnabled' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` is thrown.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Linq does not know that `ExtendedO` is of type `O`. All it's properties except the attached one are null.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
return from o in collection
       select new O()
       {
           OtherProperty = o.OtherProperty,
           HasCalculatedProperties = true,
           Value = 2
       };
```

This will create a copy of the original object with the changes you require and avoid all the messiness that come with modifying an entity in a select clause.

Comment: But in this case, where is the original object "o" stored? Or does he automaticly applie "O"'s properties, since a new object of the same type is created? ... I'll give it a try.

Comment: Compiler tells me that a complex type "O" cannot be created in a Linq To Entities query.

Creating a class "OExtended" where "O" is a property of OExtended works unter Linq To Entities. But in this case the query's result is not of type "O", but "OExtended" of course.